# Solr search by beginning of each word

Tags: solr

I need to implement a search that would look for beginning of each word. Let's say we have a document with value:

```
target: "New World"
```

I would like to be able to find that document by example following phrases: "ne", "wo", "ne wo".

The first two phrases are easy to implement. The problem is with the last one. I have tried the following query:

```
"q=target:(+ne* +wo*)"
```

and it works. But the solution seems a bit ugly for me and I am wondering if there is something faster and cleaner? Tried using TermQueries and Suggesters but nothing seemed to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the Complex Phrase Query Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser).

It'll allow you to write `q={!complexphrase inOrder=true}target:"ne* wo*"`, which differs from your example that `world new` won't generate a hit.

Your other option is to [use a EdgeNgramFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/filter-descriptions.html) and then search with `target:"ne wo"`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Mats. I think in my case the EdgeNgramFilter won’t be a good solution, cause it would generate large number of tokens - my fields sometimes have more than 20 characters. The complex phrase looks nice, but does it have same performance as my soultion? I was thinking about OR in AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory suggester, but I haven’t found anywhere any option to do that. Is it possible?

Comment: It should be just as performant; if you want to actually have positions matter, using the ComplexPhraseQueryParser would be an requirement (i.e. "World New" shouldn't match). The EdgeNgramFilter is rather efficient, since it only generates from the front of the token and not everything between (as the NgramFilter does). So with 20 characters, your worst case would be a 20x increase in the number of tokens (not index size), which depending on the size of your index, usually will be very livable and performant. Test it before dismissing it.

Comment: Great, will test both solutions. Thanks a lot!